# Angular 6 Prod build running blank page after upgrading from Angular 5

Tags: django, angular, angular5, angular6

My team's Angular app was using Angular 5 and production builds to our django app worked perfectly fine.  However, after we upgraded to Angular 6, we can no longer run `ng build` properly.  We our Output directory is our django app's static files, where Django can reference the bundle.  the django app starts up, spits out no console errors, and just hosts a blank white page.  I assume it has to do with some change between Angular 5 to 6 and the default production build settings.

Our old build command used to be:

`ng build --prod --aot --output-path="../ClientApp/static/angular" --deploy-url /static/angular`

And this build worked perfectly every time, exporting our angular bundle to our Django app's directory.  However, running this same build in Angular 6 does not work as intended, as I spoke about above.

We have changed our `Angular.json` to include an `href: "/"` in our default build options but that does not seem to help either.  Again, there are no errors to try and solve, it just seems like the `.js` files are just not running properly or there is something off with our `href`, even though it was fine before the upgrade

Has anyone else run into this problem?  I can't seem to find a good solution or changes for prod builds from Angular 5 -> 6.

I'll provide any additional details that might help find a solution.

Comment: Following the build, are the files in the directory you'd expect them?

Comment: Yes, there are exported properly and our references in Django are recognizing them.

Comment: no errors in the console, no.

Comment: Few things: 1) Did you upgrade your own code, or just npm deps? Can you cross-check _everything_ on this list: https://update.angular.io/?
2) You say `ng build` does not work as intended. How exactly does it not work as intended? Any build output, build errors or similar? What do `ng lint` or `ng test` do?

Comment: @Zlatko I should say that the build is successful, but running that build does not work as expected, due to none of the routing working and the app-root not projecting any content

Comment: Lint prints out a few lines of recommended fixes, but nothing that seems to be breaking the build

Comment: Ok, "none of the routing working" is getting us somewhere. Did you convert your rxjs syntax to rxjs@6? Do you have any route guards? Can you, as an experiment, remove the route guards and see if any of them matches?

Comment: Yeah, I did convert all our rxjs references and updated the method calls, and all that works when I serve locally, but not in our build.  I'll remove the guards and see if that changes anything.

Comment: However, we have certain pages that do not have guards and we cannot navigate to those either

Comment: Any lazy routes?

Comment: I believe in Angular 6+ you need to have ending `/` on your deploy url like `--deploy-url /static/angular/`.

Comment: @penleychan Thank you, I added that ending `/` but does not seem to have an effect on my build remaining as a blank page :/